# Populating a column by finding max

Tags: mysql

Below is the output of one of my subquery. I am stuck at one point.

```
ID         | Principal  | Price     |  Difference
102522     | 47000      | 99.9285   |
102522     | 47000      | 100.6801  |  
102522     | 47000      | 99.9285   |  
102522     | 47000      | 100.6801  |  
102522     | 47000      | 99.9285   |  
102522     | 47000      | 100.6801  |  
1048798    | 280000     | 102.3823  |  
1048798    | 280000     | 102.3666  |
1048798    | 280000     | 102.3823  |
1048798    | 280000     | 102.3666  |
1048798    | 280000     | 102.3823  |
1048798    | 280000     | 102.3666  |
1048798    | 280000     | 102.7026  |
```

I want to populate the column Difference.

It should be the difference between MAX price for given ID and price for a specific ID.

for eg.

```
ID         | Principal  | Price     |  Difference
102522     | 47000      | 99.9285   |  100.6801 - 99.9285
102522     | 47000      | 100.6801  |  100.6801 - 100.6801
102522     | 47000      | 99.9285   |  100.6801 - 99.9285
102522     | 47000      | 100.6801  |  100.6801 - 100.6801
102522     | 47000      | 99.9285   |  100.6801 - 99.9285
102522     | 47000      | 100.6801  |  100.6801 - 100.6801
1048798    | 280000     | 102.3823  |  
1048798    | 280000     | 102.3666  |
1048798    | 280000     | 102.3823  |
1048798    | 280000     | 102.3666  |
1048798    | 280000     | 102.3823  |
1048798    | 280000     | 102.3666  |
1048798    | 280000     | 102.7026  |
```

I will appreciate any pointers on how should I proceed?

Comment: 1. Attend lectures. 2. Read lecture notes. 3 Google select

Comment: What platform are you using (Sql Server, MySql, etc.)

Comment: @EdHeal . . . Geek's profile does not scream student (to me).  I would rather guess a programmer who is becoming interested in databases.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - His(?) contains very little. So I am interested in your justification that this person is not a student. The question seems to me to be homework(ish)

Comment: @EdHeal I agree with Gordon, Geek looks like a developer who is getting into SQL, I am always learning new things, windowing functions like this were new to me two years ago.

Comment: @Ed Heal - No I am not a student, I am professional and started learning SQL now. This question looks a homework because I tried to simplify it as much I could.

Comment: Perhaps post the SQL query that you have tried

Comment: @geek when you're new to something like SQL you run the risk of oversimplifying a question, I've seen questions given non working answers because they don't work based on other parts of the query (often when involving groupings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is a windowing function for your max. `MAX(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY ID)` will give you the maximum price for each ID on each row, then you just subtract the price on that row, so your statement looks like this

```
Select ID, Pricipal, Price, MAX(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) - Price AS Difference
FROM (subquery)
```

Comment: Thanks, something like PARTITION is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Just use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (max(t.price) over (partition by t.id) - t.price) as difference
from t;
```

Comment: Does that work in MySQL? That PARTITION seems to be something else in the docs, but I've not encountered this technique before, so I don't know if I understand.

Comment: Looks like [version 8 of MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html), this question should probably be tagged MSSQL if it's specific to a vendor.